# Application to check if Glassfish server has locked up

Tags: java, selenium, glassfish

I've been messing around trying to create an application that can alert our system admins if or glassfish server has gone down. To do this I have Selenium login to the server and try to find "You are signed in as" on the page and if not, then it opens a bat file that will email the system admins. Can anyone guide me on what I am missing?

```
public class Example {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://Example.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExample() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/portal/web/guest");
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).sendKeys("kyle.hoover@example.net");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("secret password");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"submit\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("You are signed in as"));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Out")).click();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) throws IOException {
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("You are signed in as"));
            Process i = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Tests\\Test2.bat\"");
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            Process i = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Tests\\Test.bat\"");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just to check if the server is running via "asadmin list-domains"?